# Spring framework default-lazy-init all beans

Tags: spring, lazy-loading, javabeans

Is there a spring property to lazy-init all beans that spring framework loads ?

I know about these properties

```
 - lazy-init="true"
 - default-lazy-init="true"
```

however there are multiple spring config xml files and some are packaged within jar so dont have liberty to change neither <bean> nor <beans> tag.

Any other way to tackle this via configuration ? or programatically ?

Comment: I really wish I could do this.  We are autowiring a lot of beans, so it takes 15-20 seconds to pre-instantiate them all.  I would love to change this on my developer machine to improve startup time, but keep it the same on the production server.

Answer (score 2):

Short of extending the Spring bean loader, none that I know of.

Answer (score 2):

You caN also use `@Lazy` annotation, but it is the same as you mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

According to java doc this should work ( though it looks not nice)

```
if (context.getBeanFactory() instanceof DefaultListableBeanFactory)
    {
        ((DefaultListableBeanFactory) context.getBeanFactory()).setAllowEagerClassLoading(false);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented this on my company, had to extend some classes of spring tough. It wasn't easy, but we gained about 20s on every tomcat startup. Unfortunately, for privacy clauses, I can't show the code, but take a look at ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner,DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader,ContextNamespaceHandler and ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser classes.

Comment: Well, its something very similar to this: http://batmat.net/blog/post/2008/01/13/How-to-load-a-XML-Spring-context-lazily-by-default, but I did also for annotated beans and beans imported from the first xml

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Spring Boot 2 you can use the **spring.main.lazy-initialization** property to configure lazy initialization across the whole application.

Setting the property value to **true** means that all the beans in the application will use lazy initialization.

in **application.yaml**

```
spring:
  main:
    lazy-initialization: true
```

or in **application.properties**

```
spring.main.lazy-initialization=true
```